# opencv2.4.4 visual studion 2012 Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am runing a program using the opencv libraray and the VS2012. I am using windows 7 64 bit, so I changed the configuration manager to x64 through project properties. In my system's enviroment variable I made these entries first from the command prompt:
`setx -m OPENCV_DIR C:\OpenCV\build` and added this to the system Path: `%OPENCV_DIR%\build\x64\vc11\bin`

In Visual Studio, in the property manager, I added the following folder links to the project properties:

1. Under C/C++, additional include directory, I added: `$(OPENCV_DIR)\include`
2. Under Linker, Additional Library Directory, I added; `$(OPENCV_DIR)\x64\vc10\lib;`
3. Linker, Input, additional dependencies, I added the following:

   `opencv_core244d.lib opencv_imgproc244d.lib opencv_highgui244d.lib opencv_ml244d.lib opencv_video244d.lib opencv_features2d244d.lib opencv_calib3d244d.lib opencv_objdetect244d.lib opencv_contrib244d.lib opencv_legacy244d.lib opencv_flann244d.lib opencv_gpu244d.lib opencv_nonfree244d.lib opencv_photo244d.lib opencv_stitching244d.lib opencv_ts244d.lib opencv_videostab244d.lib`

when I ran my program, I had this error

> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\configuration\ConsoleApplication0\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication0.exe'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_core244d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_imgproc244d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui244d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_a4d6a923711520a9\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_objdetect244d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'ConsoleApplication0.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> The program '[4228] ConsoleApplication0.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with not having the PDB for a third party library, per se. Do you actually need to debug the OpenCV code?

Comment: but as you saw the program has exited with code1 (0x1), the program is not doing wht is suppose to do

Comment: So debug your program? Or are you suggesting that the missing PDB translates into a return code of 1?

Comment: i alreadu debug it , and alrikai said the eroor is caused by another thing i will try to figure what is it yhank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those are fatal error messages. Those are merely diagnostic statements (e.g. nothing is wrong, it's just informing you of certain events).

The PDB file is a Visual Studio specific file that has the debugging symbols for your project. If you're using the pre-build libs/dlls for OpenCV, you won't have any of those files. Luckily, you can ignore those messages, unless you're hoping to step into the code for those dlls with the debugger.

If it bothers you enough, you can re-build opencv from source and enable the `/ZI` or `/Zi` option. As it stands however, none of those messages would indicate anything being wrong. Your program exiting with code 1 (0x1) is caused by something else, but you haven't provided enough information to determine what.

[Here's the official description of PDB files from MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> A program database (PDB) file holds debugging and project state information that allows incremental linking of a Debug configuration of your program. A PDB file is created when you compile a C/C++ program with /ZI or /Zi

Comment: thank you for your help , i will try to figure what is causing the error