# Visual Studio, symbols loaded

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

As I've started doing programs on Visual Studio, there appeared errors about symbols (not found), so I fixed the server and folder for cache. Nevertheless I am met by problems such as:

```
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.

The program '[4964] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I found the similar problem on the [opencv2.4.4 visual studion 2012 Cannot find or open the PDB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205498/opencv2-4-4-visual-studion-2012-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file) , but there the guy had x64 OS, furthermore the error was 0x1.

Comment: What the problem here exactly? Your stack trace shows everything was loaded and then that the program exited successfully.

Comment: Symbols being loaded is not causing a problem in your application... there is nothing wrong with that output. Your program completed and returned 0

Answer (score 0):

it's no error as i see.. 0x0 is good compiling

If you wrote on c++, you can add smth like `getc` or `cin`, and your program don't close after running

Comment: Oh..Thanks too much! But isn't it possible to use the console without such a command?

Comment: as i remember only at rad studio console app don't close after ending. or you can run it from console