# Errors using OpenCV 2.4.10 on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files

Information:
Windows 8.1 64-bit
Visual Studio 2013
OpenCV 2.4.10

I need OpenCV to do some image processing for my college group, but I can't even being learning how to use OpenCV's functions because I can't seem to get it to work with Visual Studio 2013. I've been trying for weeks using various tutorials and videos that are all so similar but always slightly different but always fail. I found this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwhTKsvHwfQ) and now It seems to work (sources at least build now)... but some samples I run don't work and the debug output says stuff like this:

'OpenCV2410Test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenCV2410Test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

There are about 50 or so "errors" like the one about in various areas and I have no idea why, it only happens on some samples though (for example, the above error came from trying to run "edge.cpp"). I've been having so many errors with this and I have no idea what to do. The only thing I can think about is my OS being 64 bit when the video has a 32-bit OS.

Help would be greatly appreciated, I want to know my setup will work when I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the errors you are seeing are likely not directly interfering with your code running - and are probably nothing to worry about!

See: [opencv2.4.4 visual studion 2012 Cannot find or open the PDB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205498/opencv2-4-4-visual-studion-2012-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file)

In the case of the "edge.cpp" sample, if the sample is not working but you are not receiving any errors beyond the 'cannot find or open the PDB file' and your code exits with code -1, this is likely due to it not finding the image it is looking for (fruits.jpg) if you imported the code into a new project to test it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In what area would I add the fruits.jpg? Do I move it to the debug folder with the exe? I just changed part of the edge.cpp so it had a path name to the fruits exact location, but it still cannot load it...

Comment: Put fruits.jpg in your _Project/Project_ folder and that should work. For example, if I created a project for this sample and named it 'Edge', there should be another folder one level down called 'Edge' that contains your source files. Place it in this folder and the sample should run.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for clearing this whole thing up! I thought my installation was wrong again!

Comment: Not a problem. If you wouldn't mind, 'accept' my answer to show that it helped you. Happy coding!